# Getting partial output in console

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, dll, console-application

I integrated the dll file generated from matlab in my C# console application. When I run the C# console application only partial output is getting displayed in the console. How can I generate the full output? Also my output in C# console application and matlab is slightly different, what could be the reason?

The matlab file use fprintf to display the data. My code in C# is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using shoes30;
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays;
using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility;

namespace shoes_try
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            shoes30.shoed_desc obj = new shoes30.shoed_desc();


           MWArray img = "C:/Users/abcd.a/Desktop/dressimages/T1k5aHXjNqXXc4MOI3_050416.jpg";
           obj.shoes(img);
        }
    }
}
```

I get only the partial output in Console. My output is abit long it consist of 1000 datas I only get the last about 150 datas.

The code in MATLAB:

```
tic;

% for the sparse vectors, just save the nonzero indices and their corresponding values
ttemp = color_weight_vec_coarse(:);
[m n] = size(ttemp);
fprintf([num2str(m) ' ' num2str(n) '\n']);
nonzero_idx = find(ttemp);
fprintf([num2str(numel(nonzero_idx)) '\n']);
for x = 1:numel(nonzero_idx)
    % zero based indexing
    fprintf([num2str(nonzero_idx(x)-1) ' ' num2str(ttemp(nonzero_idx(x))) '\n']);
end

% for the sparse vectors, just save the nonzero indices and their corresponding values
ttemp = color_weight_vec_fine(:);
[m n] = size(ttemp);
fprintf([num2str(m) ' ' num2str(n) '\n']);
nonzero_idx = find(ttemp);
fprintf([num2str(numel(nonzero_idx)) '\n']);
for x = 1:numel(nonzero_idx)
    % zero based indexing
    fprintf([num2str(nonzero_idx(x)-1) ' ' num2str(ttemp(nonzero_idx(x))) '\n']);
end

ttemp = shoe_grad_pyramid_shape(:);
[m n] = size(ttemp);
fprintf([num2str(m) ' ' num2str(n) '\n']);
for x = 1:m
    for y = 1:n
        if y<n
            fprintf([num2str(ttemp(x,y)) ' ']);
        else
            fprintf([num2str(ttemp(x,y)) '\n']);
        end
    end
end

ttemp = shoe_grad_pyramid_texture(:);
[m n] = size(ttemp);
fprintf([num2str(m) ' ' num2str(n) '\n']);
for x = 1:m
    for y = 1:n
        if y<n
            fprintf([num2str(ttemp(x,y)) ' ']);
        else
            fprintf([num2str(ttemp(x,y)) '\n']);
        end
    end
end
toc;
return;
```

Comment: Without more information it will be very difficult for anyone to help. Perhaps post what you have so far.

Comment: I have given my code. I did not use Console.Write as in matlab I have used fprintf to print the datas. I am getting outputs but only partial.

Comment: What do you mean **only partial output**? And where in your code does it output anything?

Comment: As I mentioned it gives only the last 150 datas from the 1000 output datas. And the output is displayed through MATLAB. In MATLAB it works fine but in the console I dont get all the output.

Comment: Can you show us the code, that you output to the console

Comment: Could it be that you output all 1000 lines, but the console has a finite buffer and only keeps the last 150? How many lines / characters are actually reproduced in your console output? Can you write another C# program (something simple) that produces more output?

Comment: more than 1000 lines. Yes may be it has a finite buffer so is there any way that we can use.